# Is the derivative an approximate value?

Tags: calculus

From the article on derivative in Wikipedia:

> The derivative of y with respect to x at a is, geometrically, the slope of the tangent line to the graph of f at (a, f(a)). The slope of the tangent line is very close to the slope of the line through (a, f(a)) and a nearby point on the graph, for example (a + h, f(a + h)). These lines are called secant lines. A value of h close to zero gives a **good approximation to the slope of the tangent line**, and smaller values (in absolute value) of h will, in general, give better approximations.

Does this mean that derivatives of functions are just approximations ? (In the sense that the value of $f(x)$ at $a$ is exact -- $f(a)$ -- whereas the derivative $f'(a)$ is not so ?)

EDIT: Based on some of the comments, is it the case then, that the slope of the line passing through $(a,f(a)$ *is* the derivative and the approximations defined by the secant line slopes approach this real derivative in the limit ?

Comment: The derivative has an exact value and is roughly the change of the function if you barely move(with more precision closer you are to $a$).

Comment: Could whoever downvoted the question care to explain why ? What about the question shows either lack of research effort, lack of clarity, lack of usefulness ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secant lines are the approximations. But if you take the limit of the approximations, you get the tangent line, which is *exactly* the true slope.

As a real world analogy, think of a moving car. To tell how fast it is going at time $t_0$, you measure out some small time $\Delta t$, and check how far you went, $\Delta x$. But your speed may have changed in the middle of your measurement! So you didn't get the exact speed at $t_0$. But if you make $\Delta t$ smaller, you'll get closer to the true value, right? So we take the limit as $\Delta t$ goes to $0$ to get the **exact** speed.

The limit of approximations is exact, in the same way that the limit of $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8}, \ldots$ is exactly $1$. None of the actual terms are $1$, but the limit is exactly $1$, by definition of the limit ($\epsilon$-$\delta$)

Answer (score 3):

No, the derivative $f'(a)$ is the **exact** slope of the line tangent to $(a, f(a))$.  Note that by definition

$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$

What the article is saying is that for very small $|h| > 0$, the slope of the secant line passing through $(a, f(a))$ and $(a + h, f(a + h))$ is a good approximation of $f'(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

> *A value of h close to zero gives a good approximation*

In the case of a derivative, *h* is not merely “close to zero”, but an actual $0$. So the error is $0$ as well.

Comment: I don't think $h$ is actually $0$.

Comment: @curryage it is the limit as it goes to zero so it can be taken as being zero. You can also take it to be some infinitesimal value, but that is slightly more complicated.

Comment: @curryage I agree that it is not actually $0$. I think an analogy is the money printer: Nobody actually possesses an infinite amount of money. However, if I own a money printer, I can be safely regarded as a man who has infinite money---no matter what big number you can come up with, I will just print that number $+1$ dollar to gain more money than you have. That is to say, I have infinite money "for all intent and purposes".

Comment: @curryage If you are familiar with asymptotic analysis, the analogy would be a money-printing competition: both you and I can print money, but if my money printer is "fundamentally better" than yours: You are free to duplicate your printer any (finite) number of times and use all of them in parallel, I would still win out at some point (e.g., my printer prints $t^2$ dollars after $t$ hours, but yours only prints $t$ in the same period).

The derivative is this money printing competition but in the infinitesimal setting.